# ORACLE SQL CASE statement - getting error

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

```
SELECT
    ZOC, UNIT,
    CASE ZOC
        WHEN ZOC = '51' THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KHULNA'
        WHEN ZOC = '52' THEN 'ZONE OPERATION JESSORE'
        WHEN XOC = '53' THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KUSHTIA'
    END
FROM 
    GNGRB.BS_CLOSING
ORDER BY 
    ZOC;
```

I get this error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
> 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 16 Column: 10

Comment: On a side note: Is `zoc` a string column or why are you using quotes (`'51'` etc.)? If it is a numeric column, you should use numbers, e.g. `WHEN ZOC = 51`.

Comment: The best solution would of course be a zones table mapping the zone strings to the zoc numbers, but I guess you know that.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two syntaxes. Decide for one.

### `CASE zoc WHEN ...`

```
SELECT 
  zoc, unit,
  CASE zoc
    WHEN 51 THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KHULNA'
    WHEN 52 THEN 'ZONE OPERATION JESSORE'
    WHEN 53 THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KUSHTIA'
  END 
FROM ...
```

### `CASE WHEN ...`

```
SELECT 
  zoc, unit,
  CASE
    WHEN zoc = 51 THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KHULNA'
    WHEN zoc = 52 THEN 'ZONE OPERATION JESSORE'
    WHEN zoc = 53 THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KUSHTIA'
  END 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ZOC, UNIT, CASE WHEN ZOC = '51' THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KHULNA'
                       WHEN ZOC = '52' THEN 'ZONE OPERATION JESSORE'
                       WHEN ZOC = '53' THEN 'ZONE OPERATION KUSHTIA'
                  END 
FROM GNGRB.BS_CLOSING 
ORDER BY ZOC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way of writing the `CASE..WHEN` statement.

1. `CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = VALUE1 THEN ... WHEN COLUMN_NAME = VALUE2 THEN .. END`
2. `CASE COLUMN_NAME WHEN VALUE1 THEN ... WHEN VALUE2 THEN ... END`

In your case, You can write it as follows:

```
SELECT ZOC,
       UNIT,
       CASE 
       --ZOC -- just remove this
           WHEN ZOC = '51' THEN
               'ZONE OPERATION KHULNA'
           WHEN ZOC = '52' THEN
               'ZONE OPERATION JESSORE'
           WHEN ZOC = '53' THEN
               'ZONE OPERATION KUSHTIA'
       END
  FROM GNGRB.BS_CLOSING
 ORDER BY ZOC;
```

-- OR

```
SELECT ZOC,
       UNIT,
       CASE ZOC
           WHEN '51'   THEN
               'ZONE OPERATION KHULNA'
           WHEN '52'   THEN
               'ZONE OPERATION JESSORE'
           WHEN '53'   THEN
               'ZONE OPERATION KUSHTIA'
       END
  FROM GNGRB.BS_CLOSING
 ORDER BY ZOC;
```